# Convert a multidimensional array to single dimensional associative jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays, associative-array

How to convert following multidimensional array to single dimensional associative array with minimum loop in jQuery?

```
array(array('a'=>3),array('b'=>2),array('c'=>4),array('d'=>3))
```

Expected result:

```
array('a'=>3,'b'=>2,'c'=>4,'d'=>3);
```

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript. JS does not have associative arrays; it has objects which perform broadly the same role, but they are not arrays. What you have will error.

Comment: `{'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':4, 'd':3}` is the JS syntax you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':4, 'd':3}
```

...is the JS syntax you're looking for in your result. JS doesn't have associative arrays in the sense that, say, PHP does: it has objects, which do (approximately) the same job.

If the code you show is valid in some other language (PHP?), it could be converted to a JSON string and when the JSON is parsed by JS you'd end up with a JS array of objects as follows:

```
[ {'a':3}, {'b':2}, {'c':4}, {'d':3} ]
```

To convert that to a JS object rather than an array of objects the simplest way is probably to make use of `jQuery.extend()`:

```
// assume some JSON.parse() or other process has created
myArr = [ {'a':3}, {'b':2}, {'c':4}, {'d':3} ]
// then

var tmpArr = myArr.slice(0);   // make shallow copy of myArr
tmpArr.unshift({});            // insert an empty object

var newObj = jQuery.extend.apply(this, tmpArr);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SqcEw/

Note that if more than one of the elements in the original array had the same property name one would clobber the other in the final object.

Further reading:

- [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) (page has some load errors at the moment, but normally this is a good reference and I'm sure MDN will fix it soon)
- [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)